# The configSource file 'Unity.xml' is also used in a parent, this is not allowed

Tags: c#, wcf, web-config, unity-container

I've got a VS 2013 c# (.NET 4.5) solution with 10 projects.
2 of them (the presentation one and a web service -WCF-) have similar config options:

- Web.config with
  `<configSections>
   <section name="unity" type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.UnityConfigurationSection, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration" />
   </configSections>`
  and
  `<unity configSource="Unity.xml" />`
- And a Unity.xml with Unity configuration, identical in both projects.

When I start the solution (I've tried to start both projects or just the WS) the presentation project starts well but the WS is not able to add a service, triggering the message:
`The configSource file 'Unity.xml' is also used in a parent, this is not allowed.`

If I delete the `<unity configSource="Unity.xml" />` line the services are added, but obviously the application doesn't work because I don't have the persistence access.

Any idea? Can I share more relevant data?
I'm deploying in IIS Express.

BTW, the project worked some weeks ago. Something must have changed, but I've got no idea of what, because I've been working with other solutions meanwhile, not this.

I'm a bit lost... As you can see :)

Thanks!

**Edit:** I forgot to say that the same project downloaded from TFS in a different machine works fine. I has to be something with my machine, but no idea of what...

Comment: Possible duplicate on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/578658/the-configsource-file-connections-config-is-also-used-in-a-parent-this-is-not)

Comment: Hi, I already saw that entrance, but I've got no project inheritance.

Comment: If I understood your problem correctly, you have two solutions that you are deploying through IIS Express. Even though they don't depend on one another, you are deploying them to the same location through IIS Express, and it looks like they are trying to use the same config file.

Comment: Not really. I've got one solution with two projects. They both uses other projects inside the same solution, but are not referenced one to each other. Both have their own Web.config and their own Unity.xml, not shared. I just talk about the two projects because one works and the other doesn't...

Answer (score 0):

Well, no way to solve it.
I've completely replaced the solution with the TFS latest version, I've put the WS project inside the Presentation project (they used the same backend anyway) and, after some configuration work, it works fine.
I'm not able to guess which problem was with the Unity.xml...

Answer (score 0):

If you got this while debugging in Visual Studio. Just close Visual Studio and delete .vs folder in the project and try again.

It should regenerate a new .vs folder with new IIS Config, this time without the conflicting IIS path.